# Wifi doesn't turn on

Tags: wireless, dual-boot

I have a HP Elitebook6930p and windows7 installed in it. I installed ubuntu 14.04.1 LTE along side windows and my wifi was working just fine until then both in ubuntu and windows 7. After I restarted my system next day after ubuntu installation my wifi wont turn on. It just stays lit orange. Please help me with this.
Thank You....

Comment: Also check http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1011790

Answer (score 0):

In your Ubuntu setting under software update check for Addtional drives or drivers tab it will suggest you a wifi driver (for me was Bradcom driver) install/activate it and restart you will see your wifi network now.